How to include a Standard Selection (TABLES PERNR.) in a Tab in SAP
I am working on an SAP Dynpro screen with a tabbed layout, and I want to include the standard selection TABLES PERNR. in one of the tabs. Specifically, my goal is to have:

Tab 1: Contains the standard personnel number selection (TABLES PERNR.).
Tab 2: Contains other elements, such as a simple checkbox (for now).

I understand that to include a selection screen in a tab, it must be wrapped in a block and added as a subscreen. However, I am unsure how to properly define and integrate the standard selection TABLES PERNR. as part of a subscreen in the first tab.
Could someone guide me on:

How to define TABLES PERNR. for use in a subscreen?
How to integrate it into the tabbed layout in the Dynpro screen?

If possible, please provide an example or point me in the right direction.
Thank you!
I attempted to include the standard selection TABLES PERNR. within a tabbed layout in an SAP Dynpro screen. Here is the code I used:
TABLES PERNR.

SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF TABBED BLOCK tab FOR 10 LINES.
SELECTION-SCREEN TAB (40) tab_tab1 USER-COMMAND tab1 DEFAULT SCREEN 1001.
SELECTION-SCREEN TAB (20) tab_tab2 USER-COMMAND tab2 DEFAULT SCREEN 1002.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK tab.

" Subscreen for Tab 1: Interface for Period and Personnel Number
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF SCREEN 1001 AS SUBSCREEN.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF SCREEN 1001.

" Subscreen for Tab 2
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF SCREEN 1002 AS SUBSCREEN.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF SCREEN 1002.

INITIALIZATION.
  tab_tab1 = 'STANDARD SELECTION'.
  tab_tab2 = 'OTHER SELECTION'.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN.

CASE sy-ucomm.
  WHEN 'TAB1'.
    MESSAGE 'STANDARD SELECTION' TYPE 'S'.
  WHEN 'TAB2'.
    MESSAGE 'OTHER SELECTION' TYPE 'S'.
ENDCASE.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  WRITE: / 'Active Tab:', tab-activetab.

I expected the standard selection screen for TABLES PERNR. to appear only within the first tab (Tab 1) of the tabbed block.
Instead, the standard selection screen TABLES PERNR. appears above the tabbed block, as if it is part of the default selection screen (SCREEN 1000), rather than being confined to Tab 1. This behavior does not align with the desired outcome, where the personnel number selection should be part of the first tab only.

I don't understand what you expect from a simple declaration like TABLES pernr, and your code doesn't make "TABLES PERNR. appears above the tabbed block". It displays nothing, it's just a declaration. Read the ABAP documentation for more information. What do you expect, what are you trying to do? Also, please provide a code in line with your declarations.

I tried to place the Tables PERNR. between
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF SCREEN AS SUBSCREEN
and
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF SCREEN,
but I got an error.
Please don't mind my silly mistakes, I'm new to ABAP programming

I guess you forgot defining the content of your subscreen: SELECT-OPTIONS s_pernr FOR pernr-pernr.

I want to display the standard selection of the period, employee number, and other fields provided by the expression 'Tables pernr.' within one tab. Another tab will contain custom fields that I will define. The functionality I want is that when I switch to the first tab, I see the standard table, and when I switch to the second tab, I see the custom fields. I hope this explanation is clear and provides enough details...

The ABAP statement TABLES table_wa doesn't display anything. TABLES is for specific stuff that you don't need here. Read the ABAP documentation for more information.
To display something in a selection screen, use any of the statements  SELECT-OPTIONS, PARAMETERS or SELECTION-SCREEN ...
For instance, you may use SELECT-OPTIONS inside subscreen 1001 for each standard field, and SELECT-OPTIONS inside subscreen 1002 for each custom field.
With the code below, here's what is displayed in the first tab of the selection screen (the second tab contains two other fields):

Note that SY-UCOMM should never be used. For selection screens, use TABLES sscrfields (TABLES is required in that case) and sscrfields-ucomm.
Code:
REPORT z_two_tabs.
TABLES sscrfields.
DATA dummy_structure_pernr TYPE pernr.
DATA:
  BEGIN OF structure_custom_fields,
    anything_1 TYPE c LENGTH 10,
    anything_2 TYPE c LENGTH 10,
  END OF structure_custom_fields.

SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF TABBED BLOCK tab FOR 10 LINES.
  SELECTION-SCREEN TAB (40) tab_tab1 USER-COMMAND tab1 DEFAULT SCREEN 1001.
  SELECTION-SCREEN TAB (20) tab_tab2 USER-COMMAND tab2 DEFAULT SCREEN 1002.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK tab.

" Subscreen for Tab 1: Interface for Period and Personnel Number
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF SCREEN 1001 AS SUBSCREEN.
SELECT-OPTIONS s_pernr FOR dummy_structure_pernr-pernr.
SELECT-OPTIONS s_massn FOR dummy_structure_pernr-massn.
SELECT-OPTIONS s_massg FOR dummy_structure_pernr-massg.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF SCREEN 1001.

" Subscreen for Tab 2
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF SCREEN 1002 AS SUBSCREEN.
SELECT-OPTIONS s_any_1 FOR structure_custom_fields-anything_1.
SELECT-OPTIONS s_any_2 FOR structure_custom_fields-anything_2.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF SCREEN 1002.

INITIALIZATION.
  tab_tab1 = 'STANDARD SELECTION'.
  tab_tab2 = 'OTHER SELECTION'.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN.
  CASE sscrfields-ucomm.
    WHEN 'TAB1'.
      MESSAGE 'STANDARD SELECTION' TYPE 'S'.
    WHEN 'TAB2'.
      MESSAGE 'OTHER SELECTION' TYPE 'S'.
  ENDCASE.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  WRITE: / 'Active Tab:', tab-activetab.

